# How to select range of filled cells using macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a button in sheet3.On the button click event I'm calling a macro.In the macro I want to select the number of cells that are filled in sheet13.How do I do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot select cells without changing the focus of your sheet.

```
Sheets("sheet13").Activate
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
```

You can, however, apply changes or read data from another sheet without changing focus.

```
Sheets("sheet13").UsedRange.Font.Bold = True
Msgbox Sheets("sheet13").UsedRange.Cells.Count
```

Comment: Please read the question again.I have a button on sheet3.So when I do active sheet it will select the range of sheet3 and not sheet 13 as I need.If you are gonna tell me that I should activate sheet13 and then do this, then that's not what I need coz this switches the focus from sheet3 to sheet13 which I don't want.

Comment: is there a way to activate the sheet but not shift the focus to that sheet

Comment: @gizgok - Per the second set of lines in the above answer, you can apply changes / read data from a sheet without activating it provided you the range or object you want to modify or read is preceded by Sheets("sheetname").

Answer (score 0):

As Variant says You cannot select cells without changing the focus of your sheet.

But you can use `SpecialCells` to select the cells

```
Sub tester()
Dim x1 As Range
Dim x2 As Range
Dim bigRange As Range
Sheets("sheet2").Select 'the page you need
Range("E9").Select  ' any select will do
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 23).Select 'select numbers, text, etc. 
Set x1 = Selection
Range("E9").Select  ' any select will do
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Select 'select formulas
Set x2 = Selection
Set bigRange = Application.Union(x1, x2) 'join both ranges
bigRange.Select
Sheets("sheet1").Select 'return to the page with the button
End Sub
```

the help of `SpecialCells` have aditional info of what can be selected.